# How can I write in a HDD on windows that I can read later on a Nokia Streaming Box 8000 (android TV)

Tags: file-system, android-tv, nokia

I just bought a Nokia Android TV with a super nice USB A 3.0 port (that was the main reason to choose it) where I want to plug my external 2.5' 2TB hdd with all my movies and music and such.

BUT, when I plug it in and the thing recognises the unit, it looks "empty". Ok, i assume the file system is not readable. I format the unit there so I make sure the HDD is readable byt the Android TV.
After format I unplug it and go to my laptop to re-copy all my stuff... my laptop sees the unit, but doesn't mount it: it's under "My PC" -> Manage -> Disk manager but cannot assign a letter to it.

[image: disk manager]

I format it then with FAT32 that I've read is readable by android and copy some movies, go back to the Nokia thing, connect it, and again not readable...

I am sure there is an easy way I'm missing here. Is there any FS that's accesible from both technologies? I've even installed WSD in my windows and I have kind of a "mount" access now but really don't know how to use it to see the unit in my explorer :)
thanks for any help!

Comment: If you format the disk on Android and it is not readable on PC side you have chosen the wrong format. Most likely you have formatted it as internal so that Android encrypts it and merges it to the internal storage. If Android does not allow to choose then there may be other problems. I would first start to experiment with smaller flash drives to avoid hitting some maximum size limitation. Try FAT32 and exFAT if they are recognized by Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility for the disk to have not enough power. Check volts and amps required.

Answer (score 0):

With Nokia Streaming box, like probably any other Android (I guess), you need to select a program - such as VLC - to read the data (movie, etc) USB stick
or external disk. This works for me.